# Core dump files are missing a few bytes

Tags: gdb, coredump

The core dump files generated when my app crashes seem systematically short of about 2692 bytes, when loading them in gdb I get :

```
BFD: Warning: [...]core is truncated: expected core file size >= 117628928, found: 117626236.
```

Sizes vary a bit but the missing part (difference between the expected size and what's found) is always between 2690 and 2693 bytes.
Before starting the app I force :

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

There's plenty of space and time for the system to write the file.

Other details that may be relevant :
- The target is an APF27.
- It runs Linux kernel 2.6.38
- The core file is generated on a SD card.
- The size of the file matches the size found by gdb.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Has this always been the case for the app, or did it start suddenly? Do you have any core files from before when this started happening?